# Refunding a captured authorization

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

am using the php api sdk found here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK but am having trouble issuing a refund.

This is the code I am using:

```
// CAPTURE THE ORIGINAL AUTHORIZATION
try
{
    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD");
    $amount->setTotal($amount_authorized);

    $capture = new Capture();
    $capture->setId($authorization_id);
    $capture->setAmount($amount);

    $authorization = Authorization::get($transaction_id, $apiContext);
    $capt = $authorization->capture($capture, $apiContext);

    if ($capt->state == 'completed')
    {
        $capture_id = $capt->id;
    }
}
catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e)
{
    $response = json_decode($e->getData());
    die('Error capturing funds: '.$response->message);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('Error capturing funds: '.$e->getMessage());
}

// REFUND THE CAPTURE
try
{
    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency("USD");
    $amount->setTotal($refund_amount);

    $refund = new Refund();
    $refund->setId($capture_id);
    $refund->setAmount($amount);

    $capture = Capture::get($capture_id, $apiContext);
    $captureRefund = $capture->refund($refund, $apiContext);

    if ($captureRefund->state == 'completed')
    {
        die('REFUNDED');
    }
}
catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e)
{
    $response = json_decode($e->getData());
    die('There was an error refunding the funds: '.$response->message);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    die('There was an error refunding the funds: '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

I get this error everytime: The requested resource ID was not found

I believe I am following the sample code on the developer site but I'll pulling my hair out.  It's probably something pretty easy I hope.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: which `try` block is outputting this error?

Comment: Sorry, the second one.  The Capture is working fine.

Comment: prolly just a typo here, but you are missing a `,` in the ::get() of the refund block. it'd be a flat-out compile error, so it won't be the cause of your 'not found' problem.

Comment: yeah thats a typo in the question, not in my code

Comment: Were the transactions that you are trying to refund processed using the REST API?  The SDK you're using is specific to REST, so it's looking for a REST resource ID.  If you're passing in a typical PayPal transaction ID I don't think that will work with the REST API/SDK.  You would need to use the RefundTransaction API instead.

Comment: The capture is working fine.  Does the refund use a different ID?  I've tried the original authorization ID and the capture ID

Comment: As far as the original transaction, I'm not sure, its done through our Magento shop.

Comment: @AndrewAngell You are right, I got a response from PayPal that said the same.  Thanks!